# Type trait to check if an Eigen type is an expression (without storage) or a Matrix or Array (with storage)?

Tags: templates, eigen, generic-programming, type-traits, eigen3

I am trying to distinguish the two types of Eigen types using some template magic.

1. types that are specialization of Matrix or Array, such as MatrixXd, VectorXd, etc. These types has its own data storage.
2. types that are expression, i.e. CwiseBinaryOp, etc. These are the types that returned by expressions like `a + b`.

Goal: the goal is to allow different behavior for the following function template:

```
template<typename T, typename Functor>
decltype(auto) func(const Functor& functor, T&& input) {
    if constexpr ([T is expression or lvalue reference of non-expression]) {
        return functor(std::forward<T>(input));
    } else /*[T is rvalue reference of non-expression]*/ {
        // update in-place
        input = functor(std::forward<T>(input));
        return std::move(input)
    }
}
```

This way I can wrap any lambda or functor (note: this functor is implemented similarly to `[](auto&& input){return [expr]`} so that it returns an expression that builds on top of input, which may or may not be an expression already) to `func` so I can have a choice of whether to work-on building up the expression around `input` or hand-over the data held by `input` to the returned object while evaluating the expression depending on whether I call `func(input)` or `func(std::move(input))`.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Edit:

Here is the solution I found:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct has_storage
 : std::is_base_of<Eigen::PlainObjectBase<std::decay_t<Derived> >, std::decay_t<Derived> >
{};

... //in func body:
if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value || !has_storage<T>::value) {...}
```

Comment: Essentially, you need to find out if `T` is derived from `Eigen::PlainObjectBase<typename T::Derived>`: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html

Comment: @chtz Thank you very much. it works. I added the solution to the end of the question.

Comment: Instead of inserting it into the question, you should add it as an answer.